# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

i am using corelocation framework it works fine but sometimes it gives exception like

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: `-[NSNull objectAtIndex:]`:  unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSString *strLink1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurents&rsz=8&sll=%f,%f&radius=1000&output=json",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:strLink1];
        NSData *data1=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
        NSError *err;
        response1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&err];
        arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
            NSString *strTitle=[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *strPhone=[[[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"phoneNumbers"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"number"];
            NSString *strAdd1=[[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"addressLines"]objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *strAdd2=[[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"addressLines"]objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *strAdd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",strAdd1,strAdd2]; 
            NSString *strLat=[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"lat"];
            NSString *strLng=[[[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"lng"];

            dictdata1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:strTitle,@"0",strAdd,@"1",strLat,@"2",strLng,@"3",strPhone,@"4", nil];
            [arrdata addObject:dictdata1];          
        }
    }
    [tblView reloadData];   
}  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *strCell=@"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    UILabel *lblTitle;
    UILabel *lblAdd;
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
        lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300, 50)];
        lblAdd=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20, 320, 50)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblAdd];         
    }

    lblTitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblTitle.text=[[arrdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"0"];

    lblAdd.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblAdd.text=[[arrdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"1"]; 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thats because one of your 'valueForKey' is null...

Comment: but avi sometimes it works fine..and sometimes it gives exception

Comment: then you have to check first: if (![yourProp isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])

Comment: You need to verify whether the `valueForKey` is an array in all cases. Log the value to check the same.

Comment: you also don't have `arrdata` set up as a property

Comment: Plus, wouldn't be better to use something like: `NSDictionnary *resultsAtIndex = [[[response1 valueForKey:@"responseData"]valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i ]`, and the use `dico valueForKey`? It more readeable afterwards, lines of code shorters.

Comment: what is the benefit to set arrdata as property.

Answer (score 4):

i check the response of the url & i think you misunderstood the way to use jsonObject

first, the reason of the crash is because of some value you want to fetch is kind of class **NSNull** but not the **NSArray** you want

second, you can not make sure how may result you can get , so you can not fixed the number of the result to **7**.

so first, you should make sure you wont get the **NSNull** object, so category your **NSDictionary**

```
- (id)objectForKeyNotNull:(id)key {
    id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (object == [NSNull null])
        return nil;

    return object;
}
```

then, change the way to use JsonObject

```
......

response1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&err];
arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for ( NSDictionay *result in response[@"responseData"][@"results"]) {
    NSString *strTitle=[result objectForKeyNotNull:@"title"];
    NSString *strPhone=[result objectForKeyNotNull:@"number"];
    NSString *strLat=[result objectForKeyNotNull:@"lat"];
    NSString *strLng=[result objectForKeyNotNull:@"lng"];

    for ( NSString* address in [result objectForKeyNotNull:@"addressLines"])
    {
        //......
    }

    ......


    dictdata1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:........];


    [arrdata addObject:dictdata1];          
}

.....
```

Comment: IOS does not consider NULL as nil and at run time it crashes..
To overcome this problem just simply compare your json string to NSNULL and then assign to string variable

   NSString *yourVariable = ([stringVariable isEqual:[NSNull null]]) ? @"" : stringVariable;